How to replace C[1] in solutions of trigonometric equations into k?
This is my code
  Table[{HoldForm[Cos[3 x + 2 Pi/5]] == Sqrt[i]/2, 
  Reduce[Sin[2 x] == Sqrt[i]/2, x, Reals]}, {i, 0, 4}]


How can I replace C1 to k, e.g


Why not /.{C[1]->k}? (C[1]'s syntax can be discovered using FullForm, while /. is ReplaceAll's postfix form, so stick it after the expression and see if it does what you need it to)

@eyorble Thank you very much.

In addition to using rules you can useGeneratedParameters, e.g.
Table[{HoldForm[Cos[3  x + 2  Pi/5]] == Sqrt[i]/2, 
   Reduce[Sin[2  x] == Sqrt[i]/2, x, Reals, 
    GeneratedParameters -> (k &)]}, {i, 0, 4}] // Expand

yields:

Note making  k a constant function suppresses  numbering constants.
